# Detect and access running SWFs locally

Tags: activex, flash

Is there a way to ask Flash Player if it plays any SWF files,
and if so, which are they ?

I guess it's easy to check for running SWFs in the browser.

I was wondering if any other application has flash content running...
can I detect that and access the swf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such information to retrieve from Actionscript directly (it would be really bad security-wise).

A workaround would be to check the total memory used by FP to detect if something else is playing (but you wouldn't know what)

Comment: Thanks for the totalMemory tip. I was guessing there was a way I could query the Flash Player through the operating system somehow. Can I check if Flash Player is running ? If so, can I check what urls is it accessing ? It's a weird idea, I don't even know if it's possible, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Oh ok, maybe you should ask more precisely then about targeted OS, environment etc.